# Get selected data array from kendo multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, multi-select

I am trying to get an array of the selected items from my Kendo multiselect, which is in the editor template of a kendo grid.

The multiselect code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
        .Name("Staff")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("FullName")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Staff"])
        .Events(events => events
            .Change("onChange")
        )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-md-7 details-editor" })
    )
```

I want to extract the selected items using JQuery - specifically, I want the DataValueField, which is an integer. I have tried several things, but have been unable to get the appropriate integers, rather than the index of the item in the ViewData collection. Some of the approaches I have tried.

```
var data = $("#Staff").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems();
var data = $("#Staff").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
```

I don't really know what to do from here, how to use one of the above or a different route to obtain the correct int array.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simpler than you would think.

```
$('#Staff').val();
```

That will return a comma delimited list of whatever is in your .DataValueField. In your case, a comma delimted list of 'ID'.

Comment: Genius is simple @lincstar182  Tanx

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.Select("onSelect")` event to the Multiselect and append the Value to hidden element every time when user selects the items using:

```
function onSelect(e) {
                 var item = e.item;
                var text = item.text();
                  var $data = $('#myHidden');
                  $data.val($data.val() + text);
            };
```

Comment: When I do this, dataItem.value is "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

To get the IDs of the selected items, you can write your onChange method as follows:

```
var onChange = function(e) {
 var arrayOfNames = this.value();
 // Do other stuff here...
};
```

Documentation for the change event which gets fired can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#events-change).

I've also written a working example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@BenSmith/aFina/4).

Comment: So this works in setting the hidden's value correctly, but when I hit update all the values in the array turn to 0 and the ModelState.IsValid condition fails. Why is that?

Comment: Turns out the above was part of a much larger problem, which is now solved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hallordylo glad you solved your problem. You should now accept an answer or answer your own question to bring your question to a close.